# Android LoginScreen webservices

Tags: android, web-services, authentication

I'm creating a login screen(username,password as two fields, Login button).Now, I have to enter the details in the fields and if the details exist in the database..then it has to enter to second screen or else has to give "invalid credentials" . Now, i want to write a webservice in android to send this data(username and password) to .net Application..which in turn takes and validates in database and checks the credentials and allow me to enter to second screen.Please help!!!

Comment: what do you want.. Web service or database or both. In case of programming what do you want JAVA or android or dotnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the restful architecture for the web services to send data to .net application.

Comment: I want webservice... and incase of programming"Android"